# Having hard time with page's bottom, when I scroll there is a white space at the bottom

Tags: html, css, removing-whitespace

First time creating my tribute page, but ran into unsolvable problem in css.
I have img on my background and on top of that I'm trying to put paragraph in the center while having opacity property. When text get little longer than 1 page. I see some white space on bottom, so my img breaks eventhough it is set as `background-image: cover;`

I have tried messing with html, body css by putting some margin properties and display: fixed properties.

```css
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
}

header {
  background-image: url("images/city.jpeg");
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position-y: 65%;
  background-position: fixed;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
}

#navi {
  float: right;
}

ul {
  float: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 400px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
}

.title {
  padding: 300px 300px;
  background-color: rgba(30, 23, 23, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 300px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
}

#lists {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tribute</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="main">

      <ul id="navi">
        <li><a href="#"> About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Music</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <fieldset id="logo">

      <legend style="color:white" ;> NEW YORK CITY</legend>


    </fieldset>

    <div class="title">
      <h1> New York City</h1>
      <p>New York City traces its origins to a trading post founded by colonists from the Dutch Republic in 1624 on Lower Manhattan; the post was named New Amsterdam in 1626. ... New York served as the capital of the United States from 1785 until 1790. It
        has been the country's largest city since 1790</p>
      <h2> Brief History</h2>
      <ul id="lists">
        <li><strong>1790 </strong> - Population: 33,131. New York becomes the largest city in America, surpassing Philadelphia.</li><br />
        <li><strong>1801 </strong> - New York Evening Post newspaper begins publication.</li><br />
        <li><strong>1805 </strong> - Yellow fever epidemic occurs, during which as many as 50,000 people are said to have fled the city</li><br />
        <li><strong>1811 </strong> - May 19: Close to 100 buildings burn down on Chatham Street.</li>
        <li><strong>1817 </strong> - New York Stock & Exchange Board[37] established.</li>
        <li><strong>1845 </strong> - New York City Police Department, and New York Art Union established. </li>
        <li><strong>1863 </strong> - July 13–16: Approximately 50,000 people riot in protest of President Abraham Lincoln's announcement of a draft for troops to fight in the American Civil War.[13] Over 100 are killed and many African Americans flee the
          city. The film Gangs of New York takes place during the draft riots.. </li>
        <li><strong>1871 </strong> - Grand Central Depot opens. </li><br />
        <li><strong>1872 </strong> - Metropolitan Museum of Art opens. </li><br />
        <li><strong>1878 </strong> - St. Patrick's Cathedral opens.. </li><br />
        <li><strong>1883 </strong> - Brooklyn Bridge opens. </li><br />
        <li><strong>1886 </strong> - October 28: Statue of Liberty dedicated. </li><br />
        <li><strong>1890 </strong> - Population: 1,710,715. </li><br />
        <li><strong>1883 </strong> - Brooklyn Bridge opens. </li><br />
        <li><strong>1883 </strong> - Brooklyn Bridge opens. </li><br />
        <li><strong>1886 </strong> - Brooklyn Bridge opens. </li><br />
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing height:100vh; and position: absolute; from the header.

```
header {
background-image: url("images/city.jpeg");
// height: 100vh;
background-size: cover;
background-position-y: 65%;
background-position: fixed; 
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
// position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: wow thanks it worked. does ```height: 100vh``` and ```position: absolute;``` conflicts with each other everytime?